# How to distribute layout weight equally in nested linear layout android

Tags: android

This is my layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mrp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sellPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            >

            <Button android:id="@+id/minusButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:background="#80ffdd10"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                />


            <Button android:id="@+id/plusButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+"
                android:background="#80ffdd10"
                />

        </LinearLayout>>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how it is coming out.

[image]

I can see these issues in this.

1. If we compare first and second row, price is last column is not right aligned.
2. Size of plus and minus button is different. How to distribute internal layout_weight=1 to 3 component equally.

Can someone help me on above 2 items.

Comment: For 1. price (last column) is never asked to be right aligned. How could it know you want it to be there?

For 2. why don't you try to do the same as you've done with all four items already? You seem to know how to do it?

Comment: @Devesh Where you are giving weightsum property of layouts?

Answer (score 1):

First I will say what I have understood from question, and I will post the solution I've tested:

1) The first issue, you want to set TextView id ="@+id/total" aligned at Right

- Just set the attribute `android:gravity = "right"` for this TextView

2) The second, you want set for all children within the linearLayout (which have the buttons (-/+) and TextView, equally distributed

- First, I put the attribute `android:weight = "1"` and `android:weightSum = "3"`
- Then for each child, set `android:layout_width = "0dp"` and `android:weight = "1"`